# Link static lib in a C++ project (OpenGL with SOIL)

Tags: c++, c, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I have built a simple graphical engine with .obj mesh loader using OpenGL. Now I want to add some textures to my meshes. I intend to use .dds files to store them. I chose SOIL library for loading, due to its simplicity.

So far, I've only used dynamic dll linking for my externals(SFML, Glew, OpenGL32). SOIL, on the other hand, is a static lib. I've seen static libs built within project solution, which apparently adds em to .exe and eliminates the need to add dlls. I also read that there's another way to link static lib by adding reference in the Linker (I'm using VC++ 2012 as my DevEnv). However, after hours of searching I failed to find a suitable tutorial on how to accomplish this.

I renamed "src" directory in SOIL distribution to "include" (just to be consistent) and added it to Additional Include Directories, added the path to the lib directory to the Linker (where libSOIL.a file was stored) and added libSOIL.a to Additional Dependencies. It gave me lnk2019 err with SOIL_load_OGL_texture. I renamed libSOIL.a to SOIL.lib adjusting it in  the linker as well - same err persisted. I proceeded to compile provided VS projects and built SOIL.lib in "VS9" and "VS8" project folders. Linking either was a failure.

In my final moment of desperation, I used extern "C", thinking SOIL is a C lib. That was totally stupid :)  I went on to read that people use g++ to link their static libs, which I have no idea how to use.

Could someone, please, provide a simple step-by-step algorithm on how to link a static lib like SOIL to a VS2012 c++ project. If you have time, a video on the subject would be absolutely awesome!
Thanks heaps for any help!

P.S. If one of my attempts seems reasonably correct to you, can lnk2019 err pop up due to me compiling in (x64)?

Comment: The `.a` extension is indicative that a library was created using the *UX command `AR`. This is a strong indication that you are trying to link to a Linux library instead of Microsoft Windows / Visual Studio. In Windows, whether a library is static-linking or dynamic-linking (import/export) it will always use the `.lib` file extension. You generally link against a library with a different file name when you change from dynamic to static, but the extension is not going to change (on Microsoft Windows anyway).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: ["You can use the static library file included in the zip (libSOIL.a works for MinGW and Microsoft compilers...feel free to rename it to SOIL.lib if that makes you happy)..."](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html)